# How to match two string parts of unique string with regex

Tags: regex, string

I have the followed standard string:

```
L0032_STARTUP{number}_20170812_110000.txt
```

For example any number at alias {number}:

```
L0032_STARTUP500_20170812_110000.txt
```

or
`L0032_STARTUP40_20170812_110000.dcaST` and other number possibility

For example for L0032_STARTUP500_20170812_110000.txt string I have already tried with followed regex:

```
(?=.*\bL0032_STARTUP\b)(?=.*\b_20170812_110000\b).*$
```

but it doesn't match
[image] 
I don't understand which REGEX string is able to match the strings example above.
Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
L0032_STARTUP\d+_20170812_110000\.\w+
```

## Demo

If you wanted to match your filenames as separate words, you could also add boundary markers to the start and end:

```
\bL0032_STARTUP\d+_20170812_110000\.\w+\b
```

I don't know what prompted use to use lookaheads, but I don't think they are necessary, and I would rather avoid them for possible performance reasons.